# Updating state in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to redux and most of things are sort of blurry. Such as updating state in redux.

Consider this, I have a container where I call a websocket

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    var socket = openSocket('https://coincap.io');
    var updateCoinData = [...this.props.cryptoLoaded]; //
     socket.on('trades', (tradeMsg) => {  
      for (let i=0; i<updateCoinData.length; i++) {

        if (updateCoinData[i]["short"] == tradeMsg.coin ) {     

        //Search for changed Crypto Value 
        updateCoinData[i]['price'] = tradeMsg['message']['msg']['price']

        //Update the crypto Value state in Redux

          }
        }
     })
  }
```

Here, I am getting the changed data from websocket, Now I want to update the state of my redux with new data.

I am getting cryptoloaded in the above code snippet from redux state when I do something like this..

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    cryptoLoaded: state.posts.itemsSucess
   // cryptoIsloading: state.posts.cryptoIsloading
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchCoin})(cryptoTicker);
```

The data in fetch coin is coming through action

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {CRYPTO_FETCHING, CRYPTO_DATA_FAIL, CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS, UPDATE_CRYPTO_DATA} from './type.js';
import {ApiCoinCap} from '../urls.js';


export const fetchCoin = () => {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({type: CRYPTO_FETCHING})
    axios.get(ApiCoinCap).then((response) => dispatch({
      type: CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS,
      payload: response.data
    })).catch(error => dispatch({
      type: CRYPTO_DATA_FAIL,
      payload: error.data
    }))
  }
}
```

**[Question]:** How can I dispatch an action to update the state?

[Update:] Here is how my reducer looks like

```
   import {CRYPTO_FETCHING, CRYPTO_DATA_FAIL, CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS} from './../actions/type.js';


const initialState = {
  itemsSomething : [],
  itemsSucess: [],
  itemsFail: []


}


export default function(state = initialState, action) {

  switch(action.type) {
    case CRYPTO_FETCHING:
    return {
      ...state,
      itemsSomething: action.payload
    }
    case CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        itemsSucess: action.payload
      }
      case CRYPTO_DATA_FAIL:
      return {
      ...state,
      itemsFail: action.payload
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Which I later combine by doing something like this

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import postReducer from './postreducer';

const rootreducer = combineReducers({
  posts: postReducer
})

export default rootreducer
```

**[Re: Question]** How can I update my existing state in Redux? i.e My websocket sends data which I want to update here

```
case CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            itemsSucess: action.payload
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Question]: How can I dispatch an action to update the state?

You can do this with mapDispatchToProps function from the react-redux library and also you will need async action creators from the redux thunk library.

your mapDispatchToProps function will look something like this

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
  return {
    crypto_success: (res) => dispatch(ACTIONS.set_crypto(res)),
  }
}
```

ACTIONS.set_crypto() will be the redux thunk you have to define in your actions file and then import the function here. something like

```
import * as ACTIONS from **Location of your actions file**
```

your axios get request should be

```
axios.get(ApiCoinCap)
 .then(res => this.props.crypto_success(res.data))
```

Finally the action creator will be this

```
export function set_crypto(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({type: ACTION_TYPES.CRYPTO_FETCH_SUCESS, payload: data})
  }
}
```

You will also need to modify your root index.js file to use redux thunk like so

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/index';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';



let store = createStore(
                        rootReducer,
                        applyMiddleware(thunk)
                      )


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
                  <App />
                </Provider>,
                document.getElementById('root'));
```

And thats it you should now be able to save data from axios calls to redux.